# Is $(43^n+44^n)/87$ composite for every odd prime $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the expression $$f(n):=\frac{43^n+44^n}{87}$$ for a positive integer $n$. The expression is an integer for odd $n$ and it can only be prime if $n$ is prime.

> It turns out that $f(n)$ is composite for every odd prime $n\le 74\ 000$ as user Aurel-BG has verified. That means a prime of this form must have more than $121\ 000$ digits. Is $f(n)$ always composite , and if yes , why ?

Considering the many candidates (positive integers $n$ such that $f(n)$ has no small factor) , I would assume that there should be such a prime number. In the range $[74\ 000, 600\ 000]$ for $n$ , the expected number of primes is roughly $1$ , so there is a reasonable chance that in this range , some $n$ does the job.

Comment: Could you give the expected values from 0 to 74000? If that number is for example 20 then either we have a very unusual coincidence, or something deeper may be going on. If it is 1 or 2 then finding no solutions is quite reasonable.

Comment: Not sure whether the heuristic is accurate for small entries , but for the range $[3,74\ 000]$ I get about $4.49$ and for $[100,74\ 000]$ about $3.07$. I assume that Aurel-BG tried some other combinations and ended in this case where he/she found no PRP. So, it is not a big surprise that no prime was yet found.

Comment: Hint: check for small factors: if n is a multiple of 3 so is the result.  
Other factors: n=14k+7 factor 71, n=18k+9  factor 73, n=26k+13 factors 53 and 79, n=30k+15 factor 61 n=59k+29 factor 29
n=82k+41 factor 83 etc.

Comment: when $n=5$ factor $401$, when $n=17$ factor $9669961606559$,...

Comment: The prime factors must by the way be congruent to $1$ modulo $n$ (if $n$ is prime). This increases the chance that for large $n$ , we get a prime.

Comment: The same question can be raised for other forms like $\frac{1-2^n+3^{n-1}}{2}$. This is the Stirling number $n\brace 3$. No value of $n$ is known for which it is prime, but this might well happen for some large $n$.

Comment: also note that $\frac{-4+6\cdot 2^n - 4 \cdot 3^n +4^n}{24}=  {n\brace 4} $ is  prime for $n=16$ and $n=40$...

Comment: New problem to wear my new device(4 times storage and 4 times ram) in ?

Comment: Good news !

$(44^{78697}+43^{78697})/87$ is a probable prime !

Comment: @Aurel-BG Great work! This probable prime has 129,333 decimal digits!